# How do I teach problem solving and logical thinking to students of age group 12-18yrs through online session

Tags: lesson-ideas, teaching-analogy, problem-structure

I am currently researching some good content/problems to teach my students. I am referring to Mensa's Book on Logical thinking, which has a good amount of puzzles for all age groups. Is there any other site I should refer to? And what are your suggestions on teaching methodology through online session?

Comment: Say more about how you communicate with the students and they with you and each other. "online" doesn't give a clear enough picture.

Comment: It will be my first time. I've thought of solving reasoning problems through powerpoint on zoom software. Is there any activity which children can do as a group that can enhance their problem solving skills?

Comment: There may be legal issues with Zoom around privacy with youngsters. I don't know the law in India, however. You should look into that.

Comment: Hi, as an 18 year old student (sorry for being here in the educators stack exchange), I can say that most children would prefer video games of physical or mental puzzles.
Instead of viewing this as a bad thing, think of it as a new tool to use. Even though it might seem weird, there are a bunch of problem solving and puzzler games out there - encourage your students to play them in their free time!

Comment: @nirshahar you are welcome: we sometimes have "how do I teach my-self ...?" questions, so definitely not just for teachers. We are about teaching and learning. And getting feedback from the students is **very** helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go back through old copies of GAMES magazine (libraries may have a stash somewhere).  They go the whole way back to something like 1977 and generally have lots of puzzles of various levels.  Apparently they merged together with another company back a couple of years ago.

https://gamesmagazine-online.com/product/vintage-games-packs/

In particular, I'm thinking of some puzzles where you are given a bunch of statements about a group of people and then have to derive all the information about them from logical inferences.  Generally, you'd have to lay out a diagram of some form and use that to either associate or block particular combinations until you figured everything out (much like sudoku but with logical constructions of words--this stuff predated sudoku by a long way).

As the teacher, you can "run the diagram" while the students can try to discuss the various implications of the statements.

Good luck.

(Edit: I just remembered a book I had a *long* time ago called "Puzzles for Pleasure" by E. R. Emmet--also a good source).